# Save file into folder

Tags: django, option-type

I'm trying save a file into a folder created from my app, but the file always is saved out of the folder.

I've the view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/sn/login/')
def upload_file(request, folder_id=None):
    user = UserProfile.objects.get_profile_user(request.user.email)
    store, created = UserStore.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if folder_id is not None:
        parent_folder = UserFolder.objects.get_parent_folder(store, folder_id)
    else:
        parent_folder = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(user, request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save(parent_folder)
            if not parent_folder:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('store_view'))
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('folder_view', args=(folder_id,)))
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm(user)
    return render_to_response('quaba/storage/upload_file.html',
                          {'form': form, 'folder': parent_folder},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
    url(r'^quaba/main/storage/upload_file/$',
        'upload_file',
        name='upload_file'),

    url(r'^quaba/main/storage/folder/(?P<folder_id>[\d]+)/upload_file/$',
        'upload_file',
        name='upload_file_in_folder')
```

And forms.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UploadFileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['file'] = forms.FileField(label='...')
        self.user = user
        self.store = UserStore.objects.get(user=user)

    def clean_file(self):
        total_size = 0
        all_files = UserFile.objects.all_files(self.store)
        if all_files:
            for fi in all_files:
                total_size = total_size+fi.file.size
        all_folders = UserFolder.objects.all_folders(self.store)
            if all_folders:
            for fo in all_folders:
                total_size = total_size + fo.get_folder_size()

        MAX_SIZE = 15728640 #12 MB
        content = self.cleaned_data['file']
        if content._size > MAX_SIZE:
            raise ValidationError('...')
        STORE_MAX = 5368709120 #5 GB
        if total_size+content._size > STORE_MAX:
            raise ValidationError('...')
        return content

    def save(self, folder):
        if folder:
            userfile = UserFile(store=self.store,
                                file=self.cleaned_data['file'],
                                creator=self.user,
                                parent_folder=folder)
        else:
            userfile = UserFile(store=self.store,
                                file=self.cleaned_data['file'],
                                creator=self.user) 
        userfile.save()
        return userfile
```

Optional argument folder_id is always None, I don't know why. Anybody can help me?

Comment: How do you call your url?

Comment: Can we see your UploadFileForm definition?

Comment: `folder_id` is not an optional paramter, nor a positional argument, it's a named parameter: `(?P<folder_id>...)`. You need to call reverse as: `reverse('upload_file_in_folder', args=(), kwargs={'folder_id': folder_id})`

Comment: Hi ryanmrubin, I added my UploadFileForm definition